# Do I have to recompile php to enable GD Library?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini, library, gd

I have a GD library on my server installed and 'enabled' but under the Configure Command in php.info it says

```
"--without-gd"
```

Is there a way to enable it through root or do I have to recompile?

EDIT: This is what it shows below under "GD"

```
  
GD Support            enabled
GD Version            bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.2.1
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support    enabled
JPG Support            enabled
PNG Support            enabled
WBMP Support            enabled
XBM Support            enabled
```

Here is my testing script:

```
//begin php
header('content-type: image/jpg');  

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('ninja.jpg');  
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);  
$size = getimagesize($_GET['src']);  
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;  
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;  
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);  

 imagejpeg($image) 

imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);  
//end php
```

Answer (score 1):

The command line shown under **Configure Command** reflects the options that the binary was built with, *not* what modules are currently available. Look below the main **Configuration** header to see if the **gd** module is loaded. If not then install the `php-gd` package and restart/reload httpd.

Comment: I've updated my question with some more information.  What doesn't make sense is when I try to run a GD script, nothing happens..

Comment: So what *does* your script do? Nothing, or not much - subtle difference :) If I recall correctly, all of the GD functions result in PHP errors if the module isn't loaded.

Comment: Well I had a simple watermark script...really strange though, it output the url... when I tried to do a variable isset, nothing happened, and when i just tried to echo out plain text, nothing happend at all... So i commented out the header (declaring it was a jpeg) and was able to get my echo out, but nothing happened with the images

Comment: Is it possible to post the watermarking code? It might be worth trying some simple GD tests to verify functionality. I have several already: http://pastebin.com/fKJZ4tx0, http://pastebin.com/VHukNERM, http://pastebin.com/2h0eUGSA, http://pastebin.com/Cj0R1x4Y

Comment: Ben, I just updated with the script.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to continue to handle a programming issue on Server Fault?

Comment: By looking at my server configuration above, can we be sure that the GD library is enabled and working and that it's probably just the script...

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on error_reporting(E_ALL); and point your browser to the image URL. Comment the type header to see any error messages that may be hidden if your browser only displays a broken pict message. And fix that missing semi-colon Ben mentioned.

Edit: And sanitize $_GET['src'] you may be opening a big security hole there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `imagecreatefrompng('ninja.jpg')` a typo? (i.e loading a JPEG into `imagecreatefrompng` which expects a PNG).

When I load a JPEG into `imagecreatefrompng`, it shows only the URL of the image like you describe. When I load a PNG watermark image, it works just fine.

**Note: I'm on Windows, it looks like you're on Linux. Your mileage may vary™, but I don't think by much.**

Comment: I noticed that as well and when i switched it, I'm still getting nothing.  Thanks for your help though ::shrug::

Comment: Then one last thing before I suggest you request to be migrated over to Stack Overflow (since I believe it's a code issue and I haven't used GD for some time, so it's not fresh in my mind) - the imagejpeg($image) is missing a semi colon on the end.

Answer (score 0):

My php copy came with `--without-gd` according to `phpinfo()` - I've just uncommented `;extension=php_gd2.dll` in php.ini and GD works fine.

Ubuntu 10, Zend server